# adding carriage return ini python

Tags: python

i am creating a caesar cipher  in python , I want to return an output based on the entered value ,If I copy some text from the word document , it has a carriage return in it at some points , that's why the interpreter only gave out of the first line of the input text.Is there any way so that i can also get output of the second line of the text . i am aiming to assign the same carriage  return value to the dictionary with the same key, i.e "carriage return ".is there any possible way to get my work done so that the interpreter can gave output of the second line also

> NOTE: adding the key in the dictionary was just an idea of completing the task